# 3 conditions in a nested Excel formula

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using 3 conditions in a nested formula, each condition has a number of variants. So far

```
=IF(I14=60,IF(AND(H10<10,D75=1),0.5,IF(I14=60,IF(AND(H10<30,D75=1),1,
```

and so on.

This works fine for condition 1 staying at 60, condition 2 runs through <10,<30,<50,<60 & >60, condition 3 remains at 1 and the output is as required.

When I change condition 1 to 45 and run through condition 2 as above with the rest of the criteria staying the same except the output, it refuses to work and returns false.

What am I doing wrong or is it too many functions for one formula? I am not familiar with VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP or pivot tables. Please can anyone help.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using nested IFs as long as you don't exceed the nesting limits.  The problem with complicated logic is that it gets hard to follow/troubleshoot and it's easy to make a mistake (and hard to locate it).  Your question doesn't contain enough information for people to figure out what your problem might be.  It would be easier if you can lay out the logic you're trying to achieve.  Add a table to the question with four columns, three for the conditions and the last for the result, and fill in the values.  There are probably multiple ways to do what you want.

Comment: What is visible above at this writing is not nested `IF()`'s... please clarify, and yes; examples are good.

Answer (score 1):

Extraolating out your formula so that is DOES work and is nested, it does indeed work just fine with the first condition equal to 60.

But it actually works just fine if you set the condition equal to 45. By that, I DO mean entering 60 in cell I14. But... not unless you change your formula in one of two ways:

1) Change the value you are testing against to be "<45", not 60. Of course, that probably would make it pointless so let's consider the second way.

2) I am making a guess here, but... at the very end of your formula, did you specify the last condition possible? Consider "=IF(A1=1,2,3)" and in that formula, the last condition possible would be the "3". Obvious to notice you've not put the condition in with a short formula, not so obvious with long nesting. In fact, lots of folks don't bother figuring how many parentheses to add at the end and just press Enter, then accept Excel's suggested 10 or whatever parentheses.

But that leaves the last condition unspecified. It does not produce an error as you are absolutely allowed to do that. But if your IF clauses do not pick a condition along the way, Excel gets to the last condition (the one when EVERY IF() has tested as false), then Excel returns that last condition ("3" in the above simple formula).

If it is not specified though, what is Excel to do? Well... it returns what it has at that moment:  "FALSE". When you put 45 in I14, you test false at each IF() and need that final condition. Or you get "FALSE" as your result.

Since you got that and not some error, I suggest you go to the last portion of your formula and after the (I'm guessing here!) "2.5" add a comma and whatever you want returned if condition 2 is >60. So maybe " , "ALL FAILS! "... but something at any rate.